# How to use unions with GraphQL buildSchema

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Here is how I am using a GraphQL schema string to create a schema and attach it to my Express server:

```
var graphql = require('graphql');
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
[...]
    return graphqlHTTP({
      schema: graphql.buildSchema(schemaText),
      rootValue: resolvers,
      graphiql: true,
    });
```

This is all very basic use of the modules. It works well and is quite convenient until I want to define a union:

```
union MediaContents = Photo|Youtube

type Media {
  Id: String
  Type: String
  Contents: MediaContents
}
```

I have found no way to make this work, querying Contents does what it has to do, returns the correct object but fails with the message `Generated Schema cannot use Interface or Union types for execution`.

Is it at all possible to use unions when using buildSchema ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's exactly why we created the `graphql-tools` package, which is like a production-ready, supercharged version of `buildSchema`: http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/resolvers.html#Unions-and-interfaces

You can simply use unions by providing a `__resolveType` method on the union, as usual with GraphQL.js:

```
# Schema
union Vehicle = Airplane | Car

type Airplane {
  wingspan: Int
}

type Car {
  licensePlate: String
}

// Resolvers
const resolverMap = {
  Vehicle: {
    __resolveType(obj, context, info){
      if(obj.wingspan){
        return 'Airplane';
      }
      if(obj.licensePlate){
        return 'Car';
      }
      return null;
    },
  },
};
```

The only change is, instead of providing your resolvers as the root object, use `makeExecutableSchema`:

```
const graphqlTools = require('graphql-tools');
return graphqlHTTP({
  schema: graphqlTools.makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: schemaText,
    resolvers: resolvers
  }),
  graphiql: true,
});
```

Also note that the signature of the resolvers will match the regular GraphQL.js style, so it's going to be `(root, args, context)` instead of just `(args, context)` which is what you get when you use the `rootValue`.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought, there is no way to do it with buildSchema. I wanted to make sure before adding one more dependency to the project :)

one more question: I don't quite understand the syntax of resolverMap, is Vehicle a class defined inline here (I've never seen that before, I'm more of a C++ person, and get confused all the time in JS :D )

Comment: This is a great answer. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are returning an object with all the information, you can add a __typename field in your object. Like this:

```
return {
  token: res.token,
  user: {
    __typename: 'YOUR_TYPE_HERE',
    ...res.user
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Easy fix!